# What kind of timestamp is this? Wrong conversion

Tags: python, timestamp, unix-timestamp, converters

I'm reading a file in python and I;m trying to convert the timestamp field into a readable form.

My timestamps have the following form:

```
174bb26825e
174bb26f5b6
174bb2641d2
174bb2705db
174bb26f390
```

When I use `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp` I get a date that is in 1970 and when I convert it online in a Unix Hex Timestamp Converter I get a date that comes from the future(52699)!

My code is the following:

```
df['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(int(x, 16))/16**4))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think they are timestamps?

Comment: I get reasonable-looking results from `datetime.fromtimestamp()` if I divide those numbers by 1000.  i.e. the timestamp is in milliseconds, not seconds.

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you that solved the problem